# A new simple rebus

Tags: riddle, rebus

A simple rebus for the community to solve. Good luck and I hope you enjoy!

[image: one] $+$ [image: two]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly too broad? I can see it being:

> Rise and shine

or

> Heart burn (heart shaped balloons)

or

> Light a candle (helium balloons are light)

or

> Rising flame

...and no doubt others

Comment: liking the second option the best

Comment: It was the second option; didn’t realize how board it could be. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> Love is in the air (the heart-shaped balloons)

Comment: While this would explain the first picture, it doesn't seem to use the second picture at all.

Comment: @Tas fire burns air, the balloons are in the air, love is in the air, illuminate confirmed.